# How to find the global minimum of a function from its Fourier transformed function.

Tags: fourier-analysis

i.e

Can $\min{f(t)}$ be expressed by $F(\omega)$?

I have a series of data in frequency space. I can do discrete Fourier transform to time space to find its minimum. But I am wondering if there is a way that I don't need to do the transform.